# Task management system with advanced scheduling

Tags: android, web-apps, todo

I'm looking for a ToDo / Task app.

I need all the regular stuff (tasks, subtasks, notifications, deadlines, categories/grouping, soma stats would be nice, syncing/backups), but I also would like two features I cannot find anywhere:

1. I want to specify the "start date" - I plan the task for future that should be active/highlighted after some date - e.g I want to buy a book after premiere (I cannot/don't want to do that now/earlier).
2. I would like to have repeating pattern, that is not based on calendar, but on the completion. Example: I want go to hairdresser between 1st and 20th of the month. I want this task to repeat itself but based on the completion date, not on the predefined schedule - so new task should have different start/end date depending if I'll do that on 1st or 20th.

I'm looking for Android app, preferably with Web interface. I'm okay with paying for it (I prefer one-time then subscription).

Thank you for any ideas you may have :)